# AtributeError en Pygame

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pygame

En el proceso de ejecución de este código de Pygame, el siguiente error aparece en mi terminal sin importar las correcciones que le haga al código:

```
AttributeError: 'naveEspacial' object has no attribute 'dibujar'
```

¿Cómo puedo correguir mi código de este error y por fin lograr ejecutar la imagen? Pero mas importante aun, ¿cómo puedo evitar que esto siga ocurriendo?

De antemano gracias.

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
# global variables
ancho = 900
alto = 480

class naveEspacial(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """Class for the thumb up ."""

def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.ImagenNave = pygame.image.load('emojione-png/1f44d.png')   

    self.rect = self.ImagenNave.get_rect()
    self.rect.centerx = ancho/2
    self.rect.centery = alto-30

    self.listaDisparo= []
    self.Vida = True

def disparar(self):
    pass    

def dibujar(self, superficie):
    superficie.blit(self.ImagenNave, self.rect)

def Spaceinvader():
    pygame.init()
    venta = pygame.display.set_mode((ancho,alto))
    pygame.display.set_caption("faceinvader")

    ImagenFondo = pygame.image.load("Image/fondo.jpg")

    jugador = naveEspacial()

    while True:
        for evento in pygame.event.get():
            if evento.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()   
                sys.exit()

        venta.blit (ImagenFondo, (0,0))
        jugador.dibujar(venta)
        pygame.display.update()

Spaceinvader()
```

**UPDATE:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes mal identado el código. Tal como está, `dibujar` es una función global, no un método de `naveEspacial`.

Comment: Confírmanos si es un error de copiado y pegado o es un error de indentación

Comment: He editado el post. El codigo ahora aparece en una captura de pantalla de ST.

Comment: @G.Michel no era necesario, leer código de una imagen es más complicado, efectivamente el problema es la indentación de tu código. Consulta, ¿has seguido algún tutorial de Python antes de lanzarte al desarrollo de juegos con Pygame?

Answer (score 3):

Como se menciona en los comentarios, el problema es la [indentación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentaci%C3%B3n), la solución es muy sencilla:

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
# global variables
ancho = 900
alto = 480

class naveEspacial(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """Class for the thumb up ."""

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.ImagenNave = pygame.image.load('emojione-png/1f44d.png')   

        self.rect = self.ImagenNave.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = ancho/2
        self.rect.centery = alto-30

        self.listaDisparo= []
        self.Vida = True

    def disparar(self):
        pass    

    def dibujar(self, superficie):
        superficie.blit(self.ImagenNave, self.rect)


def Spaceinvader():
    pygame.init()
    venta = pygame.display.set_mode((ancho,alto))
    pygame.display.set_caption("faceinvader")

    ImagenFondo = pygame.image.load("Image/fondo.jpg")

    jugador = naveEspacial()

    while True:
        for evento in pygame.event.get():
            if evento.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()   
                sys.exit()

        venta.blit (ImagenFondo, (0,0))
        jugador.dibujar(venta)
        pygame.display.update()

Spaceinvader()
```

Observa como ahora que se ha indentando un nivel a `__init__`, `disparar` y `dibujar`, Python los considera como **métodos** de la clase `naveEspacial`.

En tú código, Python las consideraba como **funciones** dentro del *scope* de tu script ya que se encontraban en el primer nivel de indentación y tu clase `naveEspacial` no encontraba el método `dibujar` que llamabas en esta línea:

```
jugador.dibujar(venta)
```

Te invito a leer el [PEP 0008 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) que es como la biblia de Python sobre el estilo de código.

### Lecturas recomendadas:

Tu error es un error muy común en las personas que recién se inician en Python, te recomiendo le des un vistazo a los siguientes enlaces:

- [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/)
- [Python para todos](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/18980633/Python%20para%20todos.pdf)
- [2.5. Indenting Code](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html) del Libro "Dive into Python"